# Android i-jetty :: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet Not Initialized

Tags: java, android, servlets, jetty, ijetty

May I know the possible reasons for Servlet not initialized. I have created a normal Servlet ( which runs completely fine ) in eclipse and Server used is Jetty.

Now I want this Servlet to run on my Android i-Jetty webserver, but it throws `javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet Not Initialized` Exception.

I am stuck over this issue for last 3 days. I have went through all the questions posted in Stack Overflow and googled it where-ever possible. If some one can help me to run my Servlet on Android WebServer i-Jetty.